# Problem with passing non-literal text to the Html.Partial() extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I would like to pass the file name of a partial view as data retrieved from the viewbag as such:

```
<div id="Zone1">@Html.Partial(ViewBag.ZoneControl1)</div>
```

Where the "ZoneControl1" property of the ViewBag is the name of the desired partial view retrieved from elsewhere (i.e. database, web service, etc.). If I include the text as a literal string i.e.:

```
<div id="Zone1">@Html.Partial("Controls/MyPartial")</div>
```

It works just fine. If I pass that literal string as a property of the ViewBag from the controller, or even just create a variable in the consuming view, i.e.:

```
@{string zone1 = "Controls/MyPartial";}
<div id="Zone1">@Html.Partial(zone1)</div>
```

It doesn't work. The page appears to be loading but never displays anything in the browser. Again, this works fine if I hardcode the partial view name, but not if it is passed as data from a variable or property. Anyone know why this is happening? If this is intended or unavoidable behavior, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dynamic in `Html.Partial` (which is what `ViewBag` is) because it accepts only strings. One quick way around this would be to cast your `ViewBag.ZoneControl`:

```
@Html.Partial((string)ViewBag.ZoneControl1)
```

As for the second part (`zone1 = "Controls/MyPartial"`) I was unable to duplicate that.

The following code is what I wrote to test it and it works just fine.

```
@{ string zone1 = "Controls/MyPartial"; }
<div>@Html.Partial(zone1)</div>
```

I assume the answer with casting the ViewBag is what you're really looking for in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I did try it with the explicit cast as a string as well (although I didn't include the in my example code), but it didn't work either. If you say that the 2nd example with the "zone1" worked for you, then something else must be afoot in my code. Thanks again, and I'll recheck my code for other problems and check back.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have no clue what it could be based on your example code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have it working now and I'm not exactly sure what fixed it. I copied the razor code\markup and deleted that view and created a new view and pasted in the old code. The only difference was that when I created the new view, via the wizard, I specified to NOT use a master page and the resulting page had code to specify:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

The original page was created using a master page and then I changed my mind and took out the layout directive entirely. Anyway, after making those changes, it WORKED! So, I initially surmised that the reason was that a view must specify "layout = null" if not using a master page. BUT, I then took out the "layout = null" code in this new page and it still worked! So... not sure what went wrong, but to sum up:

As @BuildStarted correctly noted, you can use a property of the ViewBag object as the partial view path, but you must cast it as a string for it to work properly. So, the premise for this question was incorrect and something else was mucking things up. Just not sure what.